# selenium extent report broken in jenkins mail

Tags: java, jenkins

I have generated extent report in selenium web driver, while attached report in editable email notification(configure-attachments), css not appended,
how to display the report with css?

Comment: Hey Ashok, the question is quite unclear. would you mind explanating it in details and adding more information to the question?